# Azure DevOps and Terraform Extension - Debug

Tags: azure, debugging, terraform, devops

Using a DevOps pipeline with the Terraform Azure extension from Peter Groenewegen 2.4.0 (Latest).
My question is in regards to setting the TF_LOG=Debug global variable using this extension and troubleshooting in general. I'm getting a vague error message,, "##[error] Terraform failed to execute. Error:" ,  and wanted to see the debug logs for troubleshooting but haven't been able to do this yet. I've tried using a separate task with an export TF_LOG=Debug or adding it to the global variables section, a tfvars file or right on the terraform apply command(##[command]"terraform" apply -auto-confirm -var 'TF_LOG=DEBUG' -input=false -no-color) with the -var TF_LOG=Debug switch. How can I enable Debug using this extension? Perhaps there is a better way to debug issues like this one? Thanks for any response.

Comment: Why using this extention while Microsoft wrote one ? 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work for the task you're using, but it's worth a shot:

For the [Microsoft terraform task for azure pipelines](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-extensions/blob/master/Extensions/Terraform/Src/Tasks/TerraformTaskV1/README.md), this can be achieved by adding the `TF_LOG` variable to the pipeline with an appropriate value.
If you go your pipeline, then click 'Edit', then go to 'Variables' and add it like so:
[image: Azure pipeline variables overview]